# Test for Loading message

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I created this simple test for loading Java Object. But unfortunately I cannot use it for large scale test with SQL queries.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{

    GetDailySalesService service = new GetDailySalesService();
    TestData obj;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {

        obj = new TestData();

        HBox hb = new HBox(100);

        Tab tabA = new Tab("test");

        Button button = new Button("Test");

        ///////////
        Region veil = new Region();
        veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)");
        veil.setPrefSize(240, 160);
        ProgressIndicator p = new ProgressIndicator();
        p.setMaxSize(140, 140);

        p.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
        veil.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
        p.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
        //tableView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());
        //tableView.setMinSize(240, 140);
        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(obj.someData(), veil, p);

        service.start();

        //////////////////
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                tabA.setContent(stack);
            }
        });

        TabPane tb = new TabPane();
        tb.setPrefSize(300, 300);

        tb.getTabs().add(tabA);

        hb.getChildren().addAll(button, tb);

        hb.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hb, 500, 300);

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    class TestData
    {

        public Label someData() throws InterruptedException
        {

            Label lb = new Label("It's working!!!!");

            Thread.sleep(6000);

            return lb;
        }
    }

    class GetDailySalesService extends Service<ObservableList<Object>>
    {

        @Override
        protected Task createTask()
        {
            return new GetDailySalesTask();
        }
    }

    class GetDailySalesTask extends Task<ObservableList<Object>>
    {

        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Object> call() throws Exception
        {

            return (ObservableList<Object>) obj.someData();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me that is the proper way to implement this test and improve the code.

Comment: Why can't you use it with SQL queries?

Comment: Because when I click on the UI component to load the Object the Application freezes for 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Inside your someData() you are making the Javafx UI thread sleep for 6 secs before returning a Label. Please review it.
In addition to it, put all your data loading event in a Task class, so that it doesn't affect the UI, while the data gets loaded from the database

Comment: Sounds very complicated. Could you please show us fixed example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `obj.someData()` inside

```
stack.getChildren().addAll(obj.someData(), veil, p);
```

You are actually calling it directly from the UI thread, I don't know why ! Try not to do it. If it's really important, try to remove

```
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

Secondly, you are using a Service class instance but you are never using it. Please go through the documentation from [JavaFX Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm#BABCCGCI) .

Just as a piece of advice, try to first play around with only [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm#BABCHBEA), before going to Service

If you still have doubts, feel free to comment !

Comment: How I can display the result from Task into the GUI?

Comment: you have to use Platform.runLater() in your Task Thread. Here is a link https://community.oracle.com/message/10864775#10864775